# how do you access internet from R

Tags: r

I used to use this to connect to internet from R. Now it says defuct, is there any other way to connect to internet, not using browser.

```
utils::setInternet2(TRUE)
```

Comment: ... do you want open a browser from R?

Comment: @manro, no browser. I need to be able to connec to r repository and install packages and be able to use Rcurl to do external api calls. So,the answer above is not valid.

Comment: Then you should correct your answer (add info) and try to remove a duplicate badge by the moderator intervention...

Comment: Run the function that you run after calling `setInternet2`, it should still work